# Inkscape PathEffects: How to remember which path to copy to clipboard?

Tags: inkscape, path-effects

Recently, I started using Inkscape regularly and more particularly the Live Path Effects.
But I am still be confused when dealing with most path effects.

Some Path Effects such the "Pattern Along Path require two paths: **the pattern** and the **path**.  Every time I use this path effect, I have to go through trial and error to get it to work because I forget which one to copy to clipboard **the pattern** or **the path** itslef.

In this case, how do you remember which one to copy to clipboard?

Thanks

Comment: If you want an analogy - think of it like hanging wallpaper.  You take sheets of wallpaper (copies of a pattern), and paste it on the wall (the path).

Comment: Maybe I am a stickler because I am use to to ruthless stack overflow & superuser communities (they are brutal) , but this really is not about graphic design.